# An example of when a product in a category may not exist.

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

My question is about the category of finitely generated Abelian groups; in particular, I want to show, by definition, that there exists a set of objects $T$ in this category for which there is no product.

I think I can choose this set $T$ to consist of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Having assumed that the product actually exists, say $P$, next I have to pick one particular object and a family of morphisms, (probably $\mathbb Z$ itself?) such that if the corresponding diagrams commute, it would lead to a contradiction regarding finitely generatedness of $P$.

Any hint would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Use the fact that $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \prod G_i) \cong \prod G_i$.

Comment: (This trick isn't available in the category of, say, finite abelian groups. A general trick is to think about $\text{Hom}(X, \prod Y)$ under the assumption that there are at least two morphisms $X \to Y$.)

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \cong G$ is not correct. The left hand side is a set, the right hand side is a group. Rather, we have $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\mathbb{Z},G) \cong G$ and hence $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \cong U(G)$, where $U(G)$ is the underlying set of $G$. This way we may recover the underlying set of a product of f.g. abelian groups, but *a priori* not the group structure. Of course this is possible, basically since any adjunction between Ab-categories is automatically Ab-enriched.

Comment: Another ad hoc proof: Assume that $\prod_i \mathbb{Z}$ exists. Then $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a direct summand for every $n$. Hence the rank is infinite. Contradiction.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks very much for your detailed answer; A quick question about the above comment: How could we say Z^n is a direct summand of the product while we are unsure of the existence and the look of the product?

Comment: More generally, if in any category with zero morphisms $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ exists, and for some subset $J \subseteq I$ also $\prod_{j \in J} A_j$ exists, then $\prod_{j \in J} A_j$ is a direct summand of $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$. You can construct (using the universal properties) homomorphisms $\prod_{j \in J} A_j \to \prod_{i \in I} A_i \to \prod_{j \in J} A_j$ which compose to the identity.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Great! It's a nice observation. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X_i)$ be a diagram of finitely generated abelian groups and assume that it has a limit $\lim_i X_i$ in the category of finitely generated abelian groups. I claim that this is also a limit in the category of abelian groups. In other words, the projections $\lim_i X_i \to X_i$ induce for every abelian group $A$ an isomorphism of sets
$$\hom(A,\lim_i X_i) \to \lim_i \hom(A,X_i).$$
In fact, we may write $A$ as a directed colimit of finitely generated abelian groups $A_j$. Then the left hand side becomes
$$\lim_j \hom(A_j,\lim_i X_i)$$
and the right hand side becomes
$$\lim_i \lim_j \hom(A_j,X_i) \cong \lim_j \lim_i \hom(A_j,X_i).$$
Here we use the general principle that limits commute with limits.
But $$\hom(A_j,\lim_i X_i) \to \lim_i \hom(A_j,X_i)$$ is an isomorphism by assumption. In the limit, we get our desired isomorphism.

It follows that a diagram of finitely generated abelian groups has a limit iff the limit of the underlying abelian groups is finitely generated.

In general one has to be more careful when one wants to compute limits and colimits in subcategories. Consider the category of torsion abelian groups. At first one might think that it has no products, since for example $\prod_{n > 0} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not torsion (and many mathematicians would agree with this argument; it has also appeared in books). But this only tells us that the product of the underlying abelian groups doesn't work. In fact there *is* a product, namely the torsion subgroup of the product of the underlying abelian groups. The same works for limits.